# In Eclipse RCP Help About Menu has scroll bar for property abouttext how to make it full size so scroll bar disappears?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

In Eclipse RCP under Help menu there is About menu, When I open the About menu the version text - abouttext - appears with scroll bar. How to resize like full screen the about menu so the full text is shown without scroll bar.

If I resize the aboutImage to a longer image than the text fits in and the scrollbar is not shown. This works like a work around. But I wonder if we can make the scroll bar disappear with out resizing the aboutImage properties gif file.

Comment: Are you asking about the standard `org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.AboutDialog`? I doubt that there is anything you can do other than changing the about image.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of what you're talking about?

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-RCP-3/tutorial3.html at the end of this link there is the screenshot of the About dialog.

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Branding/branding-your-application.html this link  has About dialog as well.